# How do I convert elements within a div to have inline css style in order to create email html code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stylesheet

I am using the code below to create inline CSS specifically to be sent via email.

The code is mainly taken from a previous question offered solution
( [What tools to automatically inline CSS style to create email HTML code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code) )

The code successfully applies inline style to all elements in the document.

Can this code modified to only apply inline style to elements within a specific DIV tag, rather than the whole document?

```
(function ($) {
  var rules = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length-1].cssRules;
  for (var idx = 0, len = rules.length; idx < len; idx++) {
    $(rules[idx].selectorText).each(function (i, elem) {
      elem.style.cssText += rules[idx].style.cssText;
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```